# Custom Link in UIWebView Bug

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView with a custom link similar to Instagram's @username mentions. However when the link is held down, Apple's default dialog box pops up, asking to open the link. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **default behavior for a long press** on any link, system wide.

I don't believe that a developer can change this.